# Change output width of plotly chart size in R Markdown PDF output

Tags: r, pdf-generation, r-markdown, knitr, r-plotly

On a R markdown file, does someone know why `out.width`,`out.height`,`figure.width` and `figure.height` parameters doesn't change plotly charts size when producing a pdf file? ( I precise that such parameters works perfectly using `plot` function)

**Please find below a reproductible example with a Rmarkdown file**

On this example, I would like the plotly chart to occupy the entire sheet like the plot chart.

````
---
title: "Change chart size chart on pdf file using plotly"
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE,message=FALSE)

```

## Parameters doesn't work with plotly  

```{r, out.width='100%',out.height='100%',fig.height=20, fig.width=15, fig.align="left"}
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = cars[1:10,]$speed,y = cars[1:10,]$dist)
```

## Parameters works using plot function

```{r,out.width='130%',out.height='100%', fig.height=20, fig.width=15, fig.align="left"}
plot(cars[1:10,])
```
````

[image]

Comment: For those rendering into HTML via knitr (rather than PDF), the out.width and out.height chunk.options will work with plotly objects. Note that since plotly has no 'auto' or '%' width/height options, you will need to set the sizing requirements in the chunks if you want something like "100%".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plotly graphs are primarily designed for interactive outputs, and as such, can behave a bit strange when being exported to static images in PDF. This issue has had some [similar posts in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401200/scaling-plotly-figures-in-knitr-latex-document), and appears to come from how webshot creates the static image.

You can fix this by forcing the plotly graph dimensions when creating the graph. The `plot_ly` function has the arguments `width` and `height` which let you set the output dimensions of the resulting plot.

If you want to include HTML objects in PDF reports, you can use the **webshot** package which essentially takes a screenshot of the rendered plots and converts it into a static image for you to include in the report. This is explained well in the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html). To install it, you will need to run:

```
install.packages('webshot')
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

Once **webshot** is installed, it should work automatically:

````
---
title: "Change chart size chart on pdf file using plotly"
output:
  pdf_document: default
papersize: a4
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(plotly)
```

```{r, out.width="100%"}
plot_ly(x = cars[1:10,]$speed,y = cars[1:10,]$dist, width = 1000, height = 1200)
```
````

[image]

Will update this answer if I can work out exactly why it works, but hope that helps!

Comment: This MWE does not produce this output with the latest versions of R/RStudio/Plotly.

Comment: Hi @oliversm, I have amended the post to make a slight tweak. It looked like it was rendering over two pages. Or was the issue something different?

Comment: In my version (all updated yesterday) it requires, `always_allow_html: true`, and also the `type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines'` added. After all that when trying to knit to pdf no figure is shown. Trying to produce pdfs with plotly seems to have this well documented pitfall https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268152/plotly-as-png-in-knitr-rmarkdown/40269138#40269138

Comment: Sounds like you might not have webshot installed? I have added to the answer to clarify as admittedly it was not that clear.

Comment: That's fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be very careful while working with plotly graphs with r markdown pdf.

While creating the plotly graph,

- Don't forget to explicitly set the size (width and height) of the graph
- Use the chunk option of out.width and out.height. They both accept pt,mm,in,px,%
- If you're producing the latex output in the pdf then 'px' will not work.

Please find the below code for the graph and the output of the same.

```
f <- list(
    size = 30,
    family = 'sans-serif'
  )
  m <- list(
    l = 100,
    r = 50,
    b = 0,
    t = 0,
    pad = 4
  )

p <- plot_ly(width = 800, height = 800) %>% 
  add_markers(data = pressure, x = pressure$temperature, y = pressure$pressure) %>% 
  layout(font = f, margin = m)
p
```

The output produced by this is
[with size and margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2mmT.png)

Now after modifying the code chunk options as below:

````
```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, out.height="150%", out.width="150%"}
f <- list(
    size = 30,
    family = 'sans-serif'
  )
  m <- list(
    l = 100,
    r = 50,
    b = 0,
    t = 0,
    pad = 4
  )

p <- plot_ly(width = 800, height = 800) %>% 
  add_markers(data = pressure, x = pressure$temperature, y = pressure$pressure) %>% 
  layout(font = f, margin = m)
p
```
````

you will get a [much bigger graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4nKd.png)

Keep coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried only using `fig.height` & `fig.width` options and remove `out.width` and `out.height`?

`{r , fig.height=6, fig.width=9.5}`

I am playing around with plotly and I've had success using HTML notebooks using this.  It's a little more trial and error but you don't have to rebuild the plots.